# showing name of Column in text view

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

in my recycle view , when user clicks on any of items, an alert dialog will show up and shows the item name and some buttons for edit,delete and..., how can I get my Item name and show it in alert dialog?

I tried set text, cursor and many things but non of the worked

here is the class i am working on

```
package com.example.hozoor;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Classes extends AppCompatActivity {
    Cursor cursor;
    TextView add;
    Database database;
    private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    private class_adaptor mclassadaptor;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    String nameclass;



    @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView ( R.layout.activity_classes );
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById ( R.id.toolbar );
        setSupportActionBar ( toolbar );

        Database mdatabase = new Database ( this );
        sqLiteDatabase = mdatabase.getWritableDatabase ();
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById ( R.id.rec_1 );
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager ( new LinearLayoutManager ( this ,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false ) );
        mclassadaptor = new class_adaptor ( this, getAllItem () );

        recyclerView.setAdapter(mclassadaptor);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById ( R.id.fab );
        fab.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder ( Classes.this );
                View view1 = getLayoutInflater ().inflate ( R.layout.custom_dialog_add_calss, null );

                final EditText New_kelas = (TextInputEditText) view1.findViewById ( R.id.name_class );
                TextView afzodn = (TextView) view1.findViewById ( R.id.btn_afzodn_new_class );
                final TextView cancel = (TextView) view1.findViewById ( R.id.btn_cancel_new_class );



                afzodn.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        if (New_kelas.getText().toString().trim().length()==0 ) {


                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText ( Classes.this, "نام کلاس را وارد کنید", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
                            String name=New_kelas.getText().toString();
                            ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
                            cv.put(Database.COLUMN_NAME,name);

                            sqLiteDatabase.insert(Database.TABLE_NAME,null,cv);

                            mclassadaptor.swapcursor(getAllItem());

                            New_kelas.getText().clear();
                        }


                    }
                } );

                cancel.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent ( getApplicationContext (), Classes.class );
                        startActivity ( intent );
                        finish ();
                    }
                } );

                builder.setView ( view1 );
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create ();
                dialog.show ();


}
        } );
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager ( layoutManager );
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new rec_listener(getApplicationContext(), recyclerView, new rec_listener.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                Intent intent =new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Situation.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }


            @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
                String id=cursor.getString ( cursor.getColumnIndex ( "_ID" ) );
                String name= (String) getText ( R.id.name_class );
                TextView name_kelas = findViewById ( R.id.txt_name_kelas );

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder ( Classes.this );
                View view1 = getLayoutInflater ().inflate ( R.layout.custom_dialog_edit_delete_bikhial, null );
                EditText New_kelas = (TextInputEditText) view1.findViewById ( R.id.name_class );

               String Name= cursor.getColumnName ( Integer.parseInt ( id ) );
                name_kelas.setText ( Name );

                builder.setView ( view1 );
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create ();
                dialog.show ();

            }
        }));

    }



    private Cursor getAllItem(){
        return sqLiteDatabase.query(
                Database.TABLE_NAME,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                Database.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP+" DESC"

        );
}

}
```

I wanted my text view to show Column name

Answer (score 1):

First of all make two alert dialog box,
first for adding value(name) and second for Show value(name).
shows Add alert dialog box in activity in which activity you want to add event, Save That event,

```
public void SaveEvent(String name) {
    databaseHelper.SaveEvent(name);
    databaseHelper.close();
    Toast.makeText(context, Name Saved!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Call this method in onCreate activity of view and also initiate databasehelper class,

```
DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
```

Call another alert box  dialog box  where you want to show details , 
and get all saved data in that view by,

```
final MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this,ShowName(name));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
            eventRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

set showname method in view

```
public void ShowName(String name) {
String name;
    SQLiteDatabase database = dbOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = databaseHelper.ShowDetail(name);
}
```

I hope this will help You!
Thanks!